# Pagination of EPUB ebook

Tags: pagination, epub

I have a EPUB ebook and parser for the same.
EPUB is in freeflow style. 
I wanted to know if there is any library available to paginate the parsed output depending on the rendering device Resolution and font size etc?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the epubjs library that they have posted on http://threepress.org/static/epubjs/. This is a pure javascript implementation that is most likely the closest thing to what you are looking for.

If you do not wish a client side javascript implementation then most likely you should be looking for a text layout engine as opposed to something that is specific to EPUB.